# Android live wallpapers

Tags: android, animation

I am new to live wallpapers. I have an animation for 2 seconds which will be looping as the live wallpaper. The problem which I face seems to be a very bad design. There are about 48 images and they are around 18 MB. Is it ok to create a simple animation using the images I have?

Comment: can u put ur code please i want to create live wallpapers with several pictures :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely it is ok. Go ahead and give it a try.